# React router doesn't handle urls containing more than one segment

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am struggling to get react router v6 to work properly. Given the below:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route index element={<div>1</div>} />
    <Route path="home" element={<div>2</div>} />
    <Route path="user" element={<div>3</div>}>
      <Route path="profile" element={<div>3.1</div>} />
      <Route path="account" element={<div>3.2</div>} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" element={<div>4</div>} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The following paths do what I expect:

- https://localhost:3000 renders `1`
- https://localhost:3000/home renders `2`
- https://localhost:3000/user renders `3`
- https://localhost:3000/other renders `4`

The following paths do not do what I expect:

- https://localhost:3000/user/profile renders a blank page rather than `3.1`
- https://localhost:3000/user/account renders a blank page rather than `3.2`
- https://localhost:3000/user/other renders a blank page rather than `4`
- https://localhost:3000/other/other renders a blank page rather than `4`

I am aware that including `<Outlet />` in the parent component (e.g. that rendered by `/user`) allows child components to render within it. However this only works with an `index` route. As soon as a second slash (e.g. `/user/account`) appears in the path, the request fails. Equally, the `*` default only renders if the unknown url contains a single `/`.

I must be doing something silly here since this example is essentially lifted from the instructions (https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6). The error the browser shows in the incorrect scenarios is (in this case the bundle.js is simply my index.html file instead of the app JS):

[image: Console error]

Comment: Even the simplest possible route involving multiple segments (e.g. `<Route path="/home/test" element={<div>content</div>} />`) renders a blank page and shows the same console error when hitting `https://localhost:3000/home/test`...

Comment: What route are you typing in browser, because on the parent route component, you have typed `<Route path="user" element={<div>3</div>}>`. In the following paths you've mentioned you've typed `http://localhost:3000/users/profile` it should be `http://localhost:3000/user/profile`

Comment: Are you typing `http://localhost:3000/user/profile` in browser?
user singular not users

Comment: Sorry typo in my question - I am typing `user`

Comment: I'm not getting a blank page, instead on accessing "user/profile" I'm getting the element defined on "user" route itself.

Comment: Which I guess is because there is no `<Outlet />`?

Comment: Thinking about this, I am using IIS and URL Rewrite behind the scenes - I wonder if this could be causing issues? This issue seems similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39967921/how-do-i-setup-react-router-clean-urls-with-iis. - I will try this and see if it fixes the issue...

Comment: So I do get to see the user/profile-Component when I include an Outlet like so:

<Route path="user" element={<><div>3</div><Outlet/></>}>

Answer (score 1):

Check this working example in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-microservice-9subu1?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help! In the end I think my issue was tied up with using IIS and URL rewrite under the hood, which none of the examples (reasonably) consider.

I hadn't properly set up my `web.config` file (as per the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39968035/5181023) or `index.html` to handle extended urls and once I had, urls with multiple segments worked as expected.

Comment: Update on this - actually that fix was unnecessary. What _really_ solved the problem was adding: `module.exports.publicPath = "/"` to my webpack config.